# Sudden CORS issue in Angular & .NET project

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular7, angular9

I have a REST service based on .NET Core as a backend and Angular 9 as a frontend. The functionality and interaction worked fine all the time. Today out of sudden, without any related change in the project it stopped working. Everytime when I use the login functionality I get the exception:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at  from origin localhost  has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource.

My backend allows to use CORS:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
    });
```

The angular's login functionality is:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  login(credentials) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');

    this.isBusy = true;

    this.http.post<any>(this.loginUrl, credentials, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(res => {   

      this.authenticate(res.body);

    }, error => { 
      sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
      this.router.navigate(['/logout'])
    })
  }


  authenticate(res) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', res);

    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it suddenly stopped working if it worked fine for months. Please advise.

Comment: It's possible that the ASP.NET Core app has started throwing errors, resulting in a 500 being returned. In that case, the CORS headers might not be getting set.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the middleware in ASP .NET Core could be an issue. Cors should be before any addition of controllers or MVC.

```
// Correctly applies Cors
services.AddCors();
services.AddControllers();

// Doesn't apply Cors
services.AddControllers();
services.AddCors();
```

The same would apply for in your `Configure(IApplicationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment)` call. I will typically make `app.UseCors()` the first line of that method.

Comment: Registering Cors is the first thing I do in  ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services). Besides, it all worked...

Comment: Is it also the first thing you do in your Configure() method?